# Birthday Problem as people enter in the room

Tags: probability, birthday

On the wikipedia page regarding the birthday problem there are several variations to it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

One of the variations is this one:

as people enter a room one at a time, which one is most likely to be the first to have the same birthday as someone already in the room? That is, for what n is p(n) − p(n − 1) maximum?

How should I do this in the most efficient way, by hand, i.e. no laptop and no calculator?

Comment: Can solve the standard birthday problem with no computing aids?  It's the same computation, more or less.

Comment: Not reliable: the median is well known to be $23$ and the mean slightly less well known to be about $24.6$, so the mode might be about $24.6 - 3\times(24.6-23) \approx 19.8$ but needs to be an integer so $20$ is a possible guess.  Then check it and $19$ and $21$

Comment: @Henry could you elaborate more? I know that for the classical birthday problem, 23 people is the minimum to have a probability of a matching birthday at least of 50%. How can you find the solution knowing only that?

Comment: I was using the empirical observation (with theoretical backing in some particular cases) that it is often the case that the difference between the mode and mean of a skew distribution is of the order of about $3$ times the difference between the median and the mode.  Sometimes this works (as in this case) and sometimes not, which is why it needs to be checked each time.

Answer (score 0):

The birthday problem (with 365 days) has the following probabilities $p(n)$ of no birthday-matches for $n=0,1,2,3..$ people
in the room:

```
L := [1.0, 1.0, 0.9972602739726028, 0.9917958341152187, 0.9836440875334497, 0.9728644263002064, 0.9595375163508885,
    0.9437642969040246, 0.925664707648331, 0.9053761661108333, 0.8830518222889223, 0.858858621678267, 0.8329752111619356,
    0.8055897247675706, 0.776897487995027, 0.7470986802363137, 0.7163959947471501, 0.6849923347034393, 0.6530885821282106,
    0.6208814739684633, 0.5885616164194201, 0.5563116648347942, 0.5243046923374499, 0.4927027656760146, 0.4616557420854712,
    0.4313002960305361, 0.401759179864061, 0.37314071773675805, 0.3455385276576006, 0.31903146252222303, 0.2936837572807313]
```

The first differences $p(n+1)-p(n)$ are

```
[0., -0.0027397260, -0.0054644399, -0.0081517466, -0.0107796612, -0.0133269099, -0.0157732195, -0.0180995893, -0.0202885415,
-0.0223243438, -0.0241932006, -0.0258834105, -0.0273854864, -0.0286922368, -0.0297988078, -0.0307026855, -0.0314036600,
-0.0319037526, -0.0322071081, -0.0323198576, -0.0322499516, -0.0320069725, -0.0316019266, -0.0310470236, -0.0303554461,
-0.0295411161, -0.0286184622, -0.0276021900, -0.0265070652, -0.0253477052]
```

which has a maximum at $n=19$.